# Doctrine DBAL: how to fetch non-integer array keys

Tags: php, doctrine

I'd like to loop over the results returned by [Doctrine DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#fetcharray) and only return the string/non-integer keys from each array. Using the below, Doctrine returns both string keys (which map to database column names) and duplicate values keyed by integers. How can I use an iterative approach and retrieve only the string/non-integer keys?

```
$stmt = $app['db']->prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row['track_name']);
}
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [field1] => foo1
    [0] => foo1
    [field2] => bar1
    [1] => bar1
)
Array
(
    [field1] => foo2
    [0] => foo2
    [field2] => bar2
    [1] => bar2
)
...
```

I'd like to get

```
Array
(
    [field1] => foo1
    [field2] => bar1
)
Array
(
    [field1] => foo2
    [field2] => bar2
)
...
```

without having to resort to

```
$fields = array('field1', 'field2');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        if (in_array($key, $fields)) {
            print_r($row[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change line

`while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {`

To

`while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)) {`

You can also use PDO:FETCH_ASSOC (seems Doctrine uses the same constant values). Other valid values are:

- HYDRATE_OBJECT
- HYDRATE_SCALAR
- HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR
- HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT